# SPA - does size matter?

Tags: java, asp.net-mvc, html, single-page-application

It seems that all the SPA examples I find, like Code Camper and ToDo are basically trivial apps.  They contain 3 or 4 lists, and 1 or 2 edit screens.   These example apps also tend to preload everything - data and html.

The app I need to build is probably 30 to 40 edit screens and 30 to 40 list/grid screens.  I probably only want to preload a few views and maybe a dashboard/widgets, then the rest is probably going to be loaded when the user navigates to the 'page'.

I want the benefits of the SPA like no page reloads and loading all the various java libraries  once.

Does anyone know of any example apps that load pages after the initial load?  I am coming from a Windows Forms C# background, so not even sure if this is possible.

Thanks, rayk

Answer (score 0):

The best example of sites that work as SPA would be sites that use jQueryMobile. In this framework, it works by loading pages using AJAX requests without actually navigating to the page.

Here's a list of sites using jQueryMobile:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/wiki/Sites-built-with-jQuery-Mobile

Answer (score 0):

That's all the SPA provides you, initially SPA will load most of the dependencies on the first page load and whenever you are navigating to some other view it will load that corresponding view dependencies which are needed additionally and not present in your cache. It does not load the dependency or functionality again if they are already present in your cache.
Better u take a look on [johnpapa.net SPA tutorial](http://www.johnpapa.net/spa/), he explained so well in his tutorials.
SPA is best for ur 30 to 40 edit screens and 30 to 40 list/grid screens.